# Fitnesse Slim query test fails while trying to access linq datacontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I wrote a query that gets a list of objects using linq.  The code executes fine in the project, but fails when I try to access it from the fitnesse project.
base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
I guess it has something to do with the connection string, but I don't know how to specify the connection string separately for the fitnesse project.  Both project and fitnesse project are part of the same solution.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
Jenny

Comment: What is the exception it throws?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where to find the app config file:

http://www.syterra.com/Slim/AppConfigFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I already tried adding a suite.config and then app config to my c:\fitnesse folder - where the .jar file is.

I added -c option c:\Fitnesse\suite.config to the command section on the test page.
Here's the suite.config file:

    
        c:\fitnesse\myapp.config
    
    
    
    
        ^.svn$

Here's the myapp.config file:

The test still fails here:

public MyDataContext() : 
                base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }